# Reading data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I  am using the below part of code for my windows application(to read every row of data from excel sheet into my c# appln). While using in VS 2003 with 1.1 Framework(using Microsoft Excel 12.0 Library) i didnt face any problems while checking for whether the cell in excel has valus or not. But when the same code has been written in VS 2010 with 4.0 Framework(Microsoft Excel 14.0 library) i am facing error like "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference". Why is that Could you please explain as it is urgent.

```
while(!Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt,j] as excel.Range).Value2).Equals(string.Empty))
{
      j++;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that you have 'range' object as a null during runtime?  Could you please confirm?  Is it always null?

Comment: no i have data's for 55 columns(till then it gets executed perfectly), but while reading 56 column(which has no data) it prduces that error.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using Range.CurrentRegion on the first cell in your range and iterate over that instead.